# Expected Value of Leaf Node's height in a Binary Search tree

Tags: data-structures

While solving problems of Expected value I came about this: Prove that, if we pick a random leaf from a binary tree with k leaves, then the expected height of this leaf is at least log(k).
Can anyone give a hint on how to proceed?

Comment: Is the binary tree balanced?

Comment: No, the binary tree can have any shape possible on k leaves.

Comment: Do you have CLRS (Introduction to Algorithms), 2nd edition? If so, look at page 265, "Randomly built binary search trees"

Comment: Basically, assume the tree is balanced and show that the expected height is about log_2 k; then show that the expected height of a leaf in a binary tree is bounded below by its expected height in a balanced binary tree.

Comment: I have proved the first part of the proof but I am not able to prove the second part. Any help on how to prove that expected height of a leaf in a binary tree is bounded below by its expected heigh in a balanced binary tree.